# How to count the highest variable Integer value

Tags: android

I have five integers, all equal to 0:

- Happy
- Neutral
- Sad
- Angry
- Stressed.

Whenever a user clicks on a particular button (Happy, Sad, etc.) for each of the integers, one will be added. This is the bit I know how to do.

Here is the part where I need help. I want to count to see which variable has the highest value, e.g. if the 'Happy' integer is 5 and the rest is three than 'Happy' is the highest. I can do this with `if` statements, but that would seem long as I would have to go through every integer. Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put them all into a `List` and use `Collections.sort(myIntegerList, Comparator.reverse());`

The highest value you can get afterwards by calling `myIntegerList.get(0);`

Answer (score 0):

It's an array of 5, just loop through it and find the biggest index which then can correlate to one of the emotions.

Comment: how do you do this though? i am fairly new with android.